# zsh zstyle: autocomplete extensions and directories

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

How do I write a `zstyle` rule that matches specific file extensions *and* directories? For instance, I want the `pylint` tool to match only `*.py` files, but also all directories (in case I need to search for a nested file); the following doesn't seem to include them.

```
zstyle ":completion:*:*:pylint:*" file-patterns "*.py"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*(-/)` glob will match directories, so simply add it to `"*.py"`, like so:

```
zstyle ":completion:*:*:pylint:*" file-patterns "*.py *(-/)"
```

Comment: Note that `"*.py" "*(-/)"`, which I've seen in several guides, doesn't do the trick for me and only matches `*.py` files. Probably a peculiarity of my setup.